# Сохранение изображения из галереи

Tags: android, java, изображения

Нажимаю на кнопку Фото, открывается галерея. Из галереи выбираю изображение. Изображение отражается на `ImageView`. Нажимаю "Добавить", изображение появляется в `ListView`. Если хочу добавить новое изображение из галереи в `ListView`, то все время добавляет первое изображение выбранное из галереи. Экран приложения:

[image: Imgur]

Как решить эту проблему?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextLastname;
private ContentValues cv;
private String name;
private String lastname;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListView mylistview;
private List<Ads> names;
static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

private ImageView imageViewPhoto;
byte[] img = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editTextLastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastname);
    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView1);
    imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);

    final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    // создаем объект для данных
    cv = new ContentValues();

    // получаем данные из полей ввода

    // подключаемся к БД
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    readSql();

    findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            imageViewPhoto.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            imageViewPhoto.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = imageViewPhoto.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] img = stream.toByteArray();



            name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            lastname = editTextLastname.getText().toString();
            cv.put("name", name);
            cv.put("lastname", lastname);
            cv.put("photo", img);



        }
    });


}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    Bitmap b = null;

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case GALLERY_REQUEST:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try {
                b = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("my", "__________");
            imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(b);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте поток закрыть, может поможет. Вообще наверняка изображение где то застревает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageViewPhoto
                    .getDrawable();

Bitmap b2 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();         
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos2);
            img = bos2.toByteArray();
            imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(b2);
```